# Am I being misled

Tags: oil

I have a 2015 VW Tiguan 2.0 TDI, DSG box.  I have just had the 30000 mile service which is oil & filter, driven home from the garage about 3/4 mile and dipped the oil to find that it is black.  Spoke to the garage who told me that this is normal for a diesel as the oil removes carbons from the engine as it runs.  I am not 100% satisfied with this as I think it unlikely that the oil would discolour after such a short journey.  Can anyone comment either way on wether or not I am being misled?

Comment: The old, "my mechanic is lying to me"... never gets old.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with diesel engines, but something doesn't seem right to me.  A couple of thoughts are:  1) buy a quart of diesel engine oil at an auto parts store, pour some in a clear container, and see what color it is; 2) send a sample of oil from your engine to an oil analysis service; 3) look around underneath the car and see if it looks obvious that you have a new oil filter.